# Do all inputs for an industry need to be delivered before it will start production?

Tags: openttd

For industries with multiple possible resources, do you need to deliver all types in order for the production of the product, or just one?

For instance, in the sub-tropical climate, do I need to deliver both fruit AND maize to the food processing plant to produce food or just one or the other?

Answer (score 12):

In the standard game (ie. without any NewGRFs installed), if an industry accepts multiple cargoes, it only requires one of them to be delivered in order to produce its own cargo.  Some NewGRFs (OpenTTD's term for mods) such as ECS change this.

There's sort of an exception to this, though: in the Sub-Tropical climate, a town in a "desert" area requires that both food and water are delivered in the same one-month period in order for it to grow.

Answer (score 0):

Just one of the input resources is generally enough for the industry to produce its output. This is certainly the case for the Temperate tileset.